Do swapped-out processes ever resurrect?
Such processes are always 4096 bytes in size (top's RES column), the SIZE column remains whatever it was normally. It's interesting that such processes' start time in ps is displayed as a hyphen (-) and STAT field has "W" in it, meaning it's been swapped out. Disabling swap space and bringing all swapped out memory to RAM doesn't fix that - they remain as swapped out and process start time remains unknown. Can such processes ever be brought back to life? If so, will their original process start time (ps start or lstart fields) reappear?
